# Styling for ListBox, ListView and GridView Items

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

The default colors for these controls seems to be similar to the Windows theme colors.  How do you change the hover, selected, selected hover and pressed colors (code or XAML)?  The following isn't working for the ListView:

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItemPresenter
        PointerOverBackground="#99CEEA"
        SelectedPressedBackground="#72BFE9"
        SelectedBackground="#72BFE9"
        SelectedPointerOverBackground="#99CEEA"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListViewItemPresenter was in the wrong place in the XAML.  Change this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItemPresenter
        PointerOverBackground="#99CEEA"
        SelectedPressedBackground="#72BFE9"
        SelectedBackground="#72BFE9"
        SelectedPointerOverBackground="#99CEEA"
        />
</ListView>
```

to this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ListViewItemPresenter
                            PointerOverBackground="#99CEEA"
                            SelectedPressedBackground="#72BFE9"
                            SelectedBackground="#72BFE9"
                            SelectedPointerOverBackground="#99CEEA" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your VS/Blend Designer, right click on your `ListView` and select

> *Edit Additional Templates* > *Edit Generated Item Container
>   (ItemContainerStyle)* > *Edit a Copy...*

[image]

In the popup window above, if you want this style to be applied to *all* your `ListViewItem`, select *Apply to all* otherwise just give it a name.

I'd recommend to create a new *Resource dictionary* for storing all `ListView` related styling. To do so, just hit the *New...* button and give the resource dictionary a name (e.g. `ListViewStyles.xaml`).

Finally, hit the *OK* button and you now have a fully generated style.

In the style's `ControlTemplate`, you can locate the `ListViewItemPresenter` control and update its colors accordingly.