# Extra whitespace appearing around Listview items

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a grid with a row that has Height="Auto".

In that row I have a listview that is bound to a list showing a string.

When those items appear in the listview they have a bunch of extra whitespace around them (If I set the background of the items there is a narrow band of that color around the text then a bunch of blank space in between the items). I am not setting any margins or padding anywhere, just a basic listview bound to my collection.

How do I get the items to show up snug next to each other instead of having a bunch of whitespace in between them

Here's the relevant XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayItems}" Grid.Row="0" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayString" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce the bottom and top space in Listview in Xaml(UWP-Universal windows platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240134/reduce-the-bottom-and-top-space-in-listview-in-xamluwp-universal-windows-platfo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800426/styling-for-listbox-listview-and-gridview-items/45805498#45805498) which might help you understand what's going on. Following my answer, you can generate the *full* default style of the `ListViewItem`.

The following `Setter`s in the style are affecting the spacing of each `ListViewItem`:

```
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="11,-1,11,-1" />
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}" />
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}" />
```

By default, `ListViewItemMinWidth` is `88` and `ListViewItemMinHeight` is `44`.

You can of course replace them all with `0` in the generated style or, simply override what you need *without* generating the full style like this

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```